# App working both on windows 8 and windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am new to windows app development and I need to create one app which will work on both windows 8 and windows 8.1 (the devices are tablets).

What is the Visual Studio version and type of app that I should use to develop my app and run it on both devices?

I am using a windows 8.1 home edition as PC.

Comment: Use Vs 2012 for  Develop Windows 8 Application Which is Compatable to Both Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Develop in windows 8 so that the will run in windows 8 and 8.1 . If you devlop in windows 8.1 it will only run in windows 8.1 @  eeadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2012 to create an app that is compatible to both these versions of the OS.